# Maven Flex - fix swf content size

Tags: actionscript-3, maven, flash

Some months ago I developed a 220x20 flash movie with a 20x20 image on the left and a label next to the image with FlashDevelop and today I wanted to port the project into a maven project.

So far so good, I got my swf file but the content inside the flash movie gets resized relative to the flash movie's size so the image and label got resized to a 1 pixel line on the upper edge of the flash movie ...

my pom.xml

```
<properties >
    <flex.sdk.version>4.5.1.21328</flex.sdk.version>
    <flexmojos.version>4.0-RC2</flexmojos.version>
</properties >

<build>
    <finalName>clipboard-action</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/as3</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.flexmojos</groupId>
            <artifactId>flexmojos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${flexmojos.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <sourceFile>com.someco/Main.as</sourceFile>ß
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.adobe.flex</groupId>
                    <artifactId>compiler</artifactId>
                    <version>${flex.sdk.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>html-wrapper</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wrapper</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <parameters>
                            <swf>${project.build.finalName}</swf>
                            <width>220</width>
                            <height>22</height>
                            <bgcolor>#FFFFFF</bgcolor>
                        </parameters>
                        <htmlName>index</htmlName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile-swf</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <compiler>
                            <optimize>true</optimize>
                        </compiler>
                        <default-size>
                            <width>220</width>
                            <height>22</height>
                        </default-size>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>flex-framework</artifactId>
        <version>${flex.sdk.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If I view the swf file only in the browser the movie has a 100% heigth and 100% width. If I view the swf inside a html page and set the html tags to width 220 and heigth 20 the flash movie gets resized correctly but the content of the movie gets resized to 1 pixel? So I assume the resizing mechanism is somehow relative?

So where can I set the width and heigth or absolute/relative resizing?

**NOTES:** the project only consists of the Main.as file and NO mxml file (I dont know what these mxml files do ...)

Comment: Try running mediainfo or a similar information software against the resultant SWF to determine if it reports the correct size (220x22), also try opening the SWF in a Flash debugger player (download one if you don't have it), it also can display the SWF in its proper size. If these both succeed to display 220x22 and a 220x22 window, then you have to recheck the HTML in order to find scaling parameters in there.

Comment: Using Flash Debug (flashplayer_17_sa_debug.exe) the swf also gets dynamically resized with the Windows size, MediaInfo says width 500 and heigth 375. but from 500px to 220px there is no relation that the label gets resized from 20px to 1px?

Comment: You've said the label gets resized to 1px at the top edge - this is what you receive by resizing a 20px high object from 375px height of the compiled SWF into a 20px view port for that SWF. Sorry, can't help with compiler configs, but check if your project is 220x22 in Flex, 500x375 is IIRC the default size for an SWF project.

Comment: @Vesper okay thank you for this information I didn't knew that. But where can I find the documentation of the flex plugins? I hardly have found some snippets around the internet about how I can use the flex framework but nothing that goes deeper in the compiler plugin ... any sources?

Answer (score 0):

After searching and searching I found the solution on stackoverflow, yay!

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3048280/1879409

I don't know how FlashDevelop handled the compilation and resizing, I configured the heigth and width somewhere in FlashDevelop and I think the Tool just added some parameters to the compiler command or something else ...